Random movement on bones that have no keyframes
When trying to clean up the motion capture on my character, I've selected a few keyframes to basically use as a base, and have deleted all the frames in between on all the bones in my character's rig. However, between these keyframes, the upper arms on my character are still.. wiggling. They're rotating slightly, even though there are no keyframes in place there. Even when setting the interpolation on everything to constant, the arms are still rotating completely on their own even as the rest of the character is perfectly still. I've tried redoing the motion capture in a separate file on the same rig, thinking that maybe something just glitched, but the same thing is happening with the same bones. What is going on??

how shall we know if you didn't provide all necessary informations? So you can either a) provide a blend file so we can check it out or b) watch some rigging tutorials to find a solution or c) hope that someone wants to "guess" what the reason could be. For me personally i don't do c) anymore because it's a waste of time (because often i got the answer "no didn't help" which is for both sides frustrating)

Hello please share the armature? https://blend-exchange.com/

.. Hi, Nelson.. it does look as if a share is needed here... stripped down to isolate the problem, but with enough stuff to let us try reproducing it

I never worked with Motion Capture, but I often hear how messy the data is. What I could guess, is that there is a bone with animation further up the hierarchy that is rotating the arm?
You just gotta look deeper into it, create a test file so your not afraid to mess something up and pick the animation apart.
Otherwise, does the rotation stop or at least change, if you set a new keyframe with other rotation than the one before and after?

I have all the bones in the rig selected, none of them have any animation on them other than the keyframes I've set. The rotation does change when I add more keyframes, but not in any way that makes sense...? It seems like it's almost reacting to physics, but I haven't put any kind of physics on the rig anywhere.

I think there are keyframes or other means of animation hidden somewhere.
What may help, if you deactivate the option "Only Keyframes from Selected Channels" under "View" on the timeline. Maybe there you will see other problematic keyframes.
Other than that I can just suggest to watch tutorials to clean up motion capture date, like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLdLwbi6OVE
